# Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: default or static interface method used without --min-sdk-version >= 24

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Here is my demo's gradle:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

I use Android-Studio 3.0, and here are [the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxfPZ.png).

Comment: I think the cause of this is that you used Java 8's feature in your project. Delete that unless you target minimum Android SDK 24.